# In Laravel validation Request, how to handle unique for different colums while update

Tags: laravel

I had a `Employee form` for its validation while update I have created a validation request as `EmployeeEdit` and while updating employee form content in controller I am passing this validation request to validate data.

but the employee form has various fields, which I have to check for uniqueness with different tables. for example, employee form has a emp_id field which i have to check for uniqueness in users table, mobile number to check-in employees table.

How to check uniqueness except for current id.

my rules in `EmployeeEdit Request`

```
return [
         'emp_id' => 'nullable|max:255|unique:users,'.$this->get('emp_id'),
         'code' => 'nullable|unique:employees|max:255'.$this->get('code'),
         'mobile_number' => 'required|unique:employees|max:255,'.$this->get('mobile_number'),
 ];
```

My Controller :

```
public function doEdit(EmployeeEdit $request, $id)
    { 
        echo "Validation passed";
        exit;
    }
```

Problem :
I don't know how to pass these fields like emp_id, mobile_number from the request so that they are ignored for the current request and should be checked for other data for uniqueness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

return [
         'emp_id' => [
                      'nullable',
                      'max:255',
                      Rule::unique('users', 'emp_id')->ignore(\Auth::user()->id),
         ],
 ];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, with your code , i have removed the auth::id() and inserted my edit id 

````
            'mobile_number' => ['nullable','max:255', Rule::unique('employees', 'mobile_number')->ignore($this->id,'user_id')],
````

on top i have used

````
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
````

And this is working fine, 
Since the id i am getting on request is from users table which is foreign key on employees table, i have mentioned the user_id column.

Comment: Was glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution from @serhii comment

Now in `EmployeeEdit Request` , i have added (on top)

`use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;`

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
                'emp_id' => ['nullable','max:255', Rule::unique('users', 'emp_id')->ignore($this->id)],
                'code' => ['nullable','max:255', Rule::unique('employees', 'code')->ignore($this->id,'user_id')],
                'mobile_number' => ['nullable','max:255', Rule::unique('employees', 'mobile_number')->ignore($this->id,'user_id')],
```

NOTE : Since the `$this->id` is id from the `users` table, in order to use it in employees table (which have `user_id` as a foreign key) I have to explicitly define a column in `employees` table rule.